# Lock row in a view

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that displays the most recent articles. However I want to add the option to lock an article on my view so it doesn't move when newer articles are added. Is there any way to do this?

So I would have to add a lock checkbox on the edit form of my article, and when checked, the article can't move on the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the "Sticky at top of lists" option on the nodes you want to keep at the top.

[image: Sticky nodes image]

Then in the sort order of your View, sort by sticky nodes first, and then your normal sort order underneath.

[image: View settings]